# Performing an SOAP Request to a service that requires NTLM Auth IIB

Tags: soap, ntlm, ibm-integration-bus

I am developing an operation in which i have to perform a SOAP request to a SQL reporting service, i already have gotten the WSDL to invoke the soap req and i built the Outputroot needed, but when i invoke the Service with the following authorization parameters:

```
    SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourceType        = 'usernameAndPassword';
    SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourceToken       = 'User';
    SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourcePassword    = 'Password';
    SET OutputRoot.Properties.IdentitySourceIssuedBy    = 'Domain';
```

I get the following message from the traces

2017-07-01 20:45:18.789668    19826   UserTrace   BIP3719I: Node 'SubflowSUB.SOAP Request Operation' sending SOAP request via transport 'HTTP' ('gg20154') for operation 'Operation' of type 'request-response'. See subsequent messages for success or failure messages relating to this request, and for any transport-specific messages.No action required.

2017-07-01 20:45:18.792716    19826   UserTrace   BIP3633I: Node 'SubflowSUB.SOAP Request Operation' sending HTTP data to URL '/ReportServer/ReportExec2005.asmx' at host 'gg20154' (port 80). The broker is sending data via HTTP to a remote server at host 'gg20154' (port 80) using URL '/ReportServer/ReportExec2005.asmx'. See subsequent messages for success or failure messages relating to this request. No action required.

2017-07-01 20:45:18.794458    19826   UserTrace   BIP3634I: Node 'SubflowSUB.SOAP Request Operation' received HTTP data from host 'gg20154' with status code of 401. The broker has received data via HTTP from a remote server at host 'gg20154' with an HTTP status code of 401. Status codes beginning with a 2 indicate success; others imply errors in either client or server. No action required.

I am using the correct credentials because i have seen how is loaded on soapui when invoking the service directly but when it is invoked by IIB it throws a 401 does anyone have had this kind of issue? and how to solve it?.

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

For credentials with basic authentication you should create a security profile with basic default and assign the user and password to this profile using the ***mqsisetdbparms*** command. With this in the SOAP Request flow in the BAR generation you have to assign the security profile created:

```
mqsisetdbparms $BRKCORP -n NAME_CRED -u <user> -p <password>
mqsicreateconfigurableservice $BRKCORP -c SecurityProfiles -o SEG_NAME_CRED -n "propagation,idToPropagateToTransport,transportPropagationConfig" -v "TRUE,STATIC ID,NAME_CRED"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for SOAP and Rest services:

```
DECLARE _AUTH CHAR 'Basic ' || BASIC64ENCODE(CAST('<username>' || ':' || '<password>' AS BLOB CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId));

SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Authentication" = _AUTH;
```